# Nested struct initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, struct, compiler-errors, initialization

So I have an issue I have been battling for a couple hours. There are a variety of questions on SO that complain about the same issue but no solutions work for me..

I have 2 structs

```
// \brief The state of a single joint position. Default value of the speed is the maximum it wil allow.
struct JointPosition
{
    /// \brief The degree to set the joint to.
    double degree = 0;
    /// \brief The max degrees per second it will allow during the move.
    double maxDegreesPerSecond = 0;
};

/// \brief Struct containing all joint positions as degrees.
struct JointPositions
{
    JointPosition base;
    JointPosition shoulder;
    JointPosition elbow;
    JointPosition wrist;
    JointPosition gripper;
    JointPosition wristRotate;
};
```

And I want to brace initialze them like this:

```
static const JointPositions pos = {
    {0, 0},
    {0, 0},
    {0, 0},
    {0, 0},
    {0, 0},
    {0, 0}
};

return pos;
```

But when I do so my compiler complains with the following error:

```
RobotArm.cpp:59:2: error: could not convert ‘{0, 0}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘JointPosition’
```

Afaik brace initializers should work with structs as long as they don't have a constructor.

I am using c++11 with gcc 7.3.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is an online link demonstrating the issue:

https://onlinegdb.com/HkKzwoLhb

Comment: @VittorioRomeo No I want to create a single JointPositions which has 6 JointPosition.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added a link to onlinegdb demonstrating the issue

Comment: The link you provide only say "C++", not e.g. "C++14". Which usually means it's C++03. However, if you remove the inline initialization in `JointPosition` it should still be fine and should compile without errors (and have done since C++ was invented, and in C before that).

Comment: Works just fine if you select C++14: https://onlinegdb.com/SyFmFiIhW

Comment: What options do you pass to gcc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the C++ version you use.

In this <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jdKQxgpGPFdkiMQy)</kbd>, I can reproduce your issue with GCC 7.2.0 and C++11.

Switching to C++14 immediately fixes the errors.

Comment: Yes C++14 indeed fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because that you already defined the "JointPosition" values as "0" in the structure. If you delete them it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

You have already initialized both data members with zero in definition of

```
struct JointPosition
{
    /// \brief The degree to set the joint to.
    double degree = 0;
    /// \brief The max degrees per second it will allow during the move.
    double maxDegreesPerSecond = 0;
};
```

All members are already initialized.

If you want to initialize them after declaration, then just remove zeros from above definition of struct JointPosition, and your program will run fine.